# Creating threads with pthread_create() doesn't work on my linux

Tags: g++, pthreads

I have this piece of c/c++ code:

```
void * myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
    int start = atoi((char*)vargp) % nFracK;

    printf("Thread start = %d, dQ = %d\n", start, dQ);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&nItermutex);
    nIter++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&nItermutex);
}

void Opt() {

    pthread_t thread[200]; 
    char start[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       sprintf(start, "%d", i);
       int ret = pthread_create (&thread[i], NULL, myThreadFun, (void*) start);
       printf("ret = %d on thread %d\n", ret, i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
}
```

But it should create 10 threads. I don't understand why, instead, it creates n < 10 threads.
The ret value is always 0 (for 10 times).

Comment: You have not provided a [mre], so it's impossible to diagnose the problem. That said: Undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-readonly non-atomic access to an object from multiple threads.

Comment: The thing is that I don't see in the output the relative:

printf("Thread start = %d, dQ = %d\n", start, dQ);

and I'm sure that not all 10 threads are created.

Comment: Did you count how many times a message containing "Thread start" is printed, regardless of what number follows it? Once you have that count, read my first comment again.

Comment: Yes! It is less than 10.

Comment: How did you check that?

Comment: Reading the stdout, checking with htop, ps -H, and seeing how many variables are updated. I'm sure that the number of threads started are less than 10 for each run.

Comment: Have you checked with something like `grep "^Thread start" | wc -l`?

Comment: Yes, I did. The output could be over 10, just because some "Thread start" repeat themself with the same following number.

Comment: That is *exactly* what I meant when I asked "Did you count how many times a message containing "Thread start" is printed, regardless of what number follows it?". Please *try* to answer these questions accurately. I'd recommend you edit the question to reflect this detail. Now that you know that this is in fact *vitally important* to answer your question, you can probably find the answer yourself with a bit of research.

Comment: The number varies, between 3 to 8. In depends on the run.

Answer (score 1):

> But it should create 10 threads. I don't understand why, instead, it creates n < 10 threads. The ret value is always 0 (for 10 times).

Your program contains at least one data race, therefore its behavior is undefined.

The provided source is also is incomplete, so it's impossible to be sure that I can test the same thing you are testing.  Nevertheless, I performed the minimum augmentation needed for `g++` to compile it without warnings, and tested that:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t nItermutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
const int nFracK = 100;
const int dQ = 4;
int nIter = 0;

void * myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
    int start = atoi((char*)vargp) % nFracK;

    printf("Thread start = %d, dQ = %d\n", start, dQ);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&nItermutex);
    nIter++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&nItermutex);
    return NULL;
}

void Opt() {

    pthread_t thread[200]; 
    char start[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       sprintf(start, "%d", i);
       int ret = pthread_create (&thread[i], NULL, myThreadFun, (void*) start);
       printf("ret = %d on thread %d\n", ret, i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
}

int main(void) {
    Opt();
    return 0;
}
```

The fact that its behavior is undefined notwithstanding, **when I run this program on my Linux machine, it *invariably* prints exactly ten "Thread start" lines**, albeit not all with distinct numbers.  The most plausible conclusion is that the program indeed does start ten (additional) threads, which is consistent with the fact that the output also seems to indicate that each call to `pthread_create()` indicates success by returning 0.  I therefore reject your assertion that fewer than ten threads are actually started.

Presumably, the followup question would be why the program does not print the expected output, and here we return to the data race and accompanying undefined behavior.  The main thread writes a text representation of iteration variable `i` into local array `data` of function `Opt`, and passes a pointer to that same array to each call to `pthread_create()`.  When it then cycles back to do it again, there is a race between the newly created thread trying to read back the data and the main thread overwriting the array's contents with new data.  I suppose that your idea was to avoid passing `&i`, but this is neither better nor fundamentally different.

You have several options for avoiding a data race in such a situation, prominent among them being:

- initialize each thread indirectly from a different object, for example:

  ```
  int start[10];

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      start[i] = i;
      int ret = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, myThreadFun, &start[i]);
  }
  ```

  Note there that each thread is passed a pointer to a different array element, which the main thread does not subsequently modify.
- initialize each thread *directly* from the value passed to it.  This is not always a viable alternative, but it is possible in this case:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      start[i] = i;
      int ret = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, myThreadFun,
              reinterpret_cast<void *>(static_cast<std::intptr_t>(i)));
  }
  ```

  accompanied by corresponding code in the thread function:

  ```
  int start = reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(vargp) % nFracK;
  ```

  This is a fairly common idiom, though more often used when writing in pthreads's native language, C, where it's less verbose.
- Use a mutex, semaphore, or other synchronization object to prevent the main thread from modifying the array before the child has read it.  (Left as an exercise.)

Any of those options can be used to write a program that produces the expected output, with each thread responsible for printing one line.  Supposing, of course, that the expectations of the output do not include that the relative order of the threads' outputs will be the same as the relative order in which they were started.  If you want that, then only the option of synchronizing the parent and child threads will achieve it.